# Finding Outlines of a Complex Shape / Large Dataset Visualization Methods

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a complicated visualization that uses data parsed from a massive .tsv file (10.2 MB!!). It's raw .wav file data, so the number of rows in the .tsv is in the hundreds of thousands. The way I constructed the shape was using a d3 path. Due to the shear number of these lines, the path technique resulted in the appearance of a solid shape as you can see in the following code + picture.

```
    d3.tsv('wav_1.tsv', function (error, rawData) {
        var data = rawData.map(function (d) {
            return {y2: +d.wav1}
        });

    var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, data.length]).range([0, w]);
    var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([-.02, .02]).range([h, 0]);
    var line = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d,i) {
            return x(i);
        })
        .y(function(d) {
            return y(d.y2);
        })

        var graph = d3.select("#graph").append("svg:svg")
              .attr("width", w + m[1] + m[3])
              .attr("height", h + m[0] + m[2])
            .append("svg:g")
              .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + m[0] + ")");

        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).tickSize(-h).tickSubdivide(true);
        graph.append("svg:g")
              .attr("class", "x axis")
              .attr("transform", "translate(0," + h + ")")
              .call(xAxis);

        var yAxisLeft = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).ticks(4).orient("left");
        graph.append("svg:g")
              .attr("class", "y axis")
              .attr("transform", "translate(-25,0)")
              .call(yAxisLeft);

        graph.append("svg:path").attr("d", line(data));
```

});

[image]

It's cool, I mean I will always think it's cool, but after working with it for a bit I have two big reasons for looking else where:

1. Ghz resources, the visualization takes about 2 seconds to load in the browser, and I feel that is too long for any static graph. Maybe by using polygons/irregular shapes/area charts this can be improved?
2. I don't have control over the fill of the shape. As it stands, there is no fill. The illusion of a fill is the result of the mish mosh of all the lines. This means that if I wanted to style with gradients, opacity or maybe textures/patterns, I'd be out of luck for the most part. However, my hunch is that if the shape could somehow be represented by an area-styled rendering, this kind of fill-styling would be much more feasible.

So that's the crux of it. I don't how much this shape can be simplified, if at all. But my goal is to keep the general outline of the shape, I don't mind losing a few edges here and there if it means ameliorating the above issues.

Just as an interesting comparison, look how soundcloud visualizes their media:

[image]

They seem to place the data into bins and use rects to simplify things. I'm not against that method, but as the title of my post suggests, I'm more interested in 1 solid shape, so that I have more control over the fill styling.

I'm curious what approaches are suggested, whether it's one of d3's dedicated methods, or if suggestions will be to manipulate more at the data-level. I'm open to anything, please feel free to brainstorm with me.

Thank you for reading!

Comment: I'd suggest that you look at using a fitler on a wrapper <g> for applying a fill/gradient to a path like this, instead of a fill. Filters treat inputs as a pixel grid, so it can solve problems like this.

Comment: I've not come across this kind of technique before, it does sound promising though. Thank you for pointing that out to me. Is there anything else I can do to improve rending when dealing with 400,000+ observations in a dataset?

Comment: There are reduction algorithms out there for large data set rendering that retain things like outliers and turning points.